# Should the [deep-network] tag be replaced by [deep-learning]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The latter is the canonical way to refer to the field, and its unclear when, if ever, [deep-network] would be preferable. Its a small change, but it'd help avoid very odd sounding questions like ["What is Deep Network?"](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/96/109)

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to this AI stuff. I started working with AI two months ago, so I don't know all the terms. :/ (I had the "very odd sounding" question.)

Comment: No worries! Just want to get the right terms out there to aid in your future learnings :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes. I don't know many people who use the term "deep network" like that. You may hear "deep neural network", but that's still basically synonymous with "deep learning" as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

If `deep-learning` is preferred, then `deep-network` should be set up as a [tag synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/135236) for it, that way if anyone tries to use it, it gets mapped to the preferred name.  We need someone with 1250 reputation to do that.

Comment: Is there some reputation threshold to be able to do that? Can't find that option :-/

Comment: @zergylord Yes 1250 is the required reputation.  I've linked to the meta answer that talks about them.