# Should [deep-network] and [deep-learning] be made synonymous?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

In this question: [Should the [deep-network] tag be replaced by [deep-learning]?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/should-the-deep-network-tag-be-replaced-by-deep-learning), it seems that it was agreed upon that the [deep-network](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-network) should be replaced by [deep-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning).

However, currently, both tags are used. The [deep-network](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-network) is used by 18 questions, the [deep-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) tag by 13 questions. Can we create a tag synonym?

Comment: Which one should be the main?

Comment: @kenorb [deep-learning] was what was said in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "deep learning" is already a standard expression, so this tag should be the main tag. The tag [deep-network](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-network) could also exist on this website, given that the expression "deep neural network" is also common, but I would not say that it is a synonym for [deep-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning). A deep network is a network that is deep (that is, it possesses "many" layers). However, deep learning is not just concerned with the architecture of the NNs, but it also concerned with the *learning* part.